# How to Control the WS-FEDERATION authentication flow in an ASP.NET CORE application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, adfs, windows-server, ws-federation

I am learning how to authenticate users in ADFS using ws-federation. For this I already have ADFS, AD DS and IIS operating.

Now, following the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-8.0) this is how my program.cs file is configured and the authentication works.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
 {
     sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 }).AddWsFederation(options =>
 {
     options.Wtrealm = "https://localhost:7114/";
     options.MetadataAddress = "https://myServer/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml";

 }).AddCookie();
```

My difficulty is; I would like to **control the authentication flow from my asp.net core** **application** but so far I cannot find documentation that can guide me.
Could someone give me some clues in this sense?
Thank you.

My difficulty is; I would like to **control the authentication flow from my asp.net core** **application** but so far I cannot find documentation that can guide me. Could someone give me some clues in this sense? Thank you.

Comment: This document related with WS-Federation might help:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: Thanks @Ruikai Feng, but the link you shared with me is the same document I am referring to above.
As you can see, in the article they only show how to implement this type of authentication and I have already done it. What I want is to be able to control the authentication flow from my asp.net core application, in the sense of: being able to redirect users based on some parameter, establish restrictions... etc.